# DietPi OS not enabling Wifi Adapter in VirtualBox

Tags: wifi

My setup:

- A laptop with VirtualBox installed containing the OS DietPi.
- The VM is in Bridge Mode. Adapter 1 is set to Bridge on the Ethernet Port and Adapter 2 is set to Bridge on the Wireless adapter.

What I'm trying to do:

- I need to turn the Wifi Adapter of the host into a Wifi Hotspot to share files and Internet connection to the devices connected to it.
- Since I'm using the Wireless adapter as a Hotspot, I'm providing the Internet through Ethernet port.

Problem:

- When I try to setup the SSID and Password for the Wifi Hostpot, it gives the following error: `No supported Wifi Hardware was found`.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It's as follows.

Virtual Machines are not allowed to access devices that are directly attached to the motherboard (I don't know the technical term for such devices), except for USB devices.

So when I connected to the Wifi using my host machine, Virtual Box "bridged" the connection to the VM as an ethernet connection. In simple terms, the VM thinks that it is connected to the network using an ethernet connection. Also since my VM is not allowed devices that are directly connected to the motherboard, my VM thinks that it doesn't have a Wireless Adapter. And that's why it gives the "`No supported Wifi Hardware was found`" error.

Solution to the problem: Use external Wifi Adapter or run the DietPi OS locally on a Raspberry Pi or on any SBC (Single Board Computer) of your choice.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.